# If $f,k\in C^{2\pi}$, then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x+t)k(t)\mathop{dt}\in C^{2\pi}$

Tags: functional-analysis

> If $f,k\in C^{2\pi}$, then show that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x+t)k(t)\mathop{dt}\in C^{2\pi}$

where $C^{2\pi}$ is the space of continuous functions with period of $2\pi$

Thoughts/Attempt:

Suppose $f,k\in C^{2\pi}$. Since the product of two continuous $2\pi$ periodic functions is still continuous and $2\pi$ periodic (I think), then $f(x+t)k(t)\in C^{2\pi}$. After taking the integral, we would get an expression in terms of $x$. However I'm not sure how to determine if this expression is in $C^{2\pi}$ without explicitly seeing the integrated function, but I assume there's a way to find out without carrying out the integration. A hint to begin would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what you want to prove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $G$ denote the integral function
$$G(x) := \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x + t) k(t) \,dt.$$
What is the integral expression for $G(x + 2 \pi)$?

Comment: I am just about to give the same hint!

Answer (score 1):

For the continuity part, you can use that continuous functions on $[-\pi, \pi]$ are uniformly continuous. By periodicity of $f$ and $k$ this means that $f$ and $k$ are uniformly continuous on all of ${\mathbb R}$. As a result, in the expression
$$G(x + h) - G(x) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(x + h + t) - f(x + t)) k(t)\,dt$$
given any $\epsilon > 0$ there's a $\delta > 0$ such that $|h| < \delta$ implies $|f(x + h + t) - f(x + t)| < \epsilon$. Hence if $|h| < \delta$ one also has
$$|G(x + h) - G(x)| \leq \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \epsilon |k(t)|\,dt$$
$$= \epsilon \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |k(t)|\,dt$$
This is just another way of stating that $G$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Nevermind; I understand. Thanks.